# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to specify request and response DTOs in MediatR

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation, mediatr

In my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API project, I am using Fluent Validation and MediatR.

Already I have this code:

Models:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public Department()
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

}
```

DTOs:

```
public class DepartmentDto : IRegister
{
    public DepartmentDto()
    {
        Employees = new List<EmployeeDto>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<EmployeeDto> Employees { get; set; }

    public void Register(TypeAdapterConfig config)
    {
        config.NewConfig<Department, DepartmentDto>();
    }
}


public class DepartmentRequestDto : IRegister
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void Register(TypeAdapterConfig config)
    {
        config.NewConfig<Department, DepartmentRequestDto>();
    }
}

public class DepartmentResponseDto : IRegister
{
    public DepartmentResponseDto()
    {
        Employees = new List<EmployeeDto>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<EmployeeDto> Employees { get; set; }

    public void Register(TypeAdapterConfig config)
    {
        config.NewConfig<Department, DepartmentResponseDto>();
    }
}
```

So far, I have this code to create a new department:

CreateDepartmentCommandValidator:

```
public class CreateDepartmentCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateDepartmentCommand>
{
    public CreateDepartmentCommandValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(v => v.Name)
            .MaximumLength(100).WithMessage("Name must not exceed 100 characters.")
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Name is required.");
    }
}
```

CreateDepartmentCommand:

```
public class CreateDepartmentCommand : IRequestWrapper<DepartmentDto>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CreateDistrictCommandHandler : IRequestHandlerWrapper<CreateDistrictCommand, DistrictDto>
{
    private readonly IApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public CreateDistrictCommandHandler(IApplicationDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<ServiceResult<DepartmentDto>> Handle(CreateDepartmentCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var entity = new District
        {
            Name = request.Name,
        };

        await _context.Departments.AddAsync(entity, cancellationToken);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        return ServiceResult.Success(_mapper.Map<DepartmentDto>(entity));
    }
}
```

Instead of the above code for CreateCommand, I want to have **DepartmentRequestDto** as the input to replace the Department Model. And also want it to return **DepartmentResponseDto** as the output (or response) instead of the **DepartmentDto** that is there.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request wrapper:

```cs
public interface IRequestWrapper<T> : IRequest<ServiceResult<T>>
{
}
```

Request handler wrapper:

```cs
public interface IRequestHandlerWrapper<in TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestHandler<TRequest, ServiceResult<TResponse>>
    where TRequest : IRequestWrapper<TResponse>
{
}
```

The request, that must implement request wrapper:

```cs
public class DepartmentRequestDto : IRequestWrapper<DepartmentResponseDto>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And handler that implements request handler wrapper:

```cs
public class CreateDepartmentCommandHandler : IRequestHandlerWrapper<DepartmentRequestDto, DepartmentResponseDto>
{
    private readonly IApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public CreateDistrictCommandHandler(IApplicationDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<ServiceResult<DepartmentResponseDto>> Handle(DepartmentRequestDto request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var entity = new District
        {
            Name = request.Name,
        };

        _context.Departments.Add(entity);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        return ServiceResult.Success(_mapper.Map<DepartmentResponseDto>(entity));
    }
}
```

The response is structured however you like and has no requirements:

```cs
public class DepartmentResponseDto
{
    // TODO: Add response model properties.
}
```

Comment: Allow me to ask this one more question.   Where is the original class........    public class CreateDepartmentCommand

Comment: The `DepartmentRequestDto` became the command. It is the input class, the request you send via Mediator's `Send()` method. You can name it however you like, but it has to implement `IRequest<TResponse>` in order to be used as first type parameter of `IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>`.